# Counterexample for approximation by convolution

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I'm currently reading [these lecture notes](http://users.jyu.fi/%7Emiparvia/Opetus/HarmonicAnalysis/4lecture.pdf). In the remark to theorem 3.7, it is explicitly stated that the convergence doesn't hold for $p= \infty$. I'm not really sure about that, as I am not able to find a counterexample.

Is there an easy counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f=1$ on $[0, 1]$ and $f=0$ elsewhere, let $\varphi=1$ on $(-\frac 12, \frac 12)$ and $\varphi=0$ elsewhere. Thus $\varphi$ has integral $1$. We see for all $\epsilon<\frac 12$, $\varphi_\epsilon* f$ is continuous: for example near $0$ we have $\varphi_\epsilon*f=0$ for $x\leq -\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and then increases linearly to $1$ at $x=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Thus for all $\epsilon<\frac 12$ we have
$$
\|\varphi_\epsilon*f-f\|_\infty=\frac 12.  
$$.

Comment: Could you explain how you get the last equation?

Comment: This is a general property. I don't remember in what generality this works exactly, but I guess the convolution of arbitrary $L^1$ functions is continuous, and in fact, a convolution of an $L^1$ function with a smooth function is smooth.

Comment: I know, but how exactly does one get the value of this norm to be equal to 0.5?

Comment: @max_121: Consider the left hand side and right hand side limits of the convolution at the discontinuity point of $f$. The equality requires some work, but inequality should be pretty clear, since you can't be closer than 1/2 to both 1 and 0 at the same time.

Comment: Oh I see; one more question - how exactly do you define the $\infty$- norm in this case? It seems that you are using the definition without a.e. and that's why this counterexample works.

Comment: This is the "essential supremum".

Comment: Ok, so there must be a non-zero subset, where $|\varphi \star f -f| > 1/2$ by definition of the essential supremum. Is it possible to explicitly find that subset?

Comment: no. it means for all $a>\frac 12$, the set $\{|\varphi_\epsilon*f-f|>a\}$ is of measure $0$, and for all $a<\frac 12$ the set $\{|\varphi_\epsilon*f-f|>a\}$ is of positive measure.

Comment: Sorry, I made an error in my question; it should have been a non-zero subset, where $|\varphi_\epsilon \star f - f| > 1/4$.